# Glimpse 403 - Forbbiden

Tags: http-status-code-403, glimpse

Using Glimpse in MVC3, I get 403 Forbbiden trying to access glimpse.axd.
Checked and rechecked configuration, integrated and not, routes for axd's, all seems fine, but it does not work.
I'm using VS2012 with IISExpress with https.

Old threads says to enable the ip, but that configuration was removed on the latest's versions.

Glimpse Core 1.7, GlimpseMVC 1.4, Glimpse AspNet 1.5

Any ideas?

Update: Last line at the logs says

```
2013-11-07 18:56:21.7801 | INFO | Runtime policy does not allow execution of resource named 'glimpse_config'. |
```

Thanks

Comment: In the latest release we secured the glimpse.axd as well. It won't be available if the `defaultRuntimePolicy` in the config is set to `Off` or if you have a custom runtime policy that runs at `RuntimeEvent.ExecuteResource` and denies access. If none of these apply to your case, would you then mind creating an issue for this [on our issue tracker](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse/issues) so that we can have a closer look? Do you have this with a clean project and fresh install as well?

Comment: Tx! defaultRuntimePolicy on fixed the issue, you should update the documentation and quickstart on the website :)

Comment: We'll do. Just keep in mind that even prior that release, that now secures the Glimpse.axd as well, accessing the Glimpse.axd and setting the cookie won't activate Glimpse if the `defaultRuntimePolicy` is set to `Off` in the web.config. You can only activate Glimpse by setting that policy to a higher value of which `On` is the highest